# Sine of argument with large n approximation

Tags: limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

I have worked an integral and reduced the integral to
$$\frac{n \pi+\sin\left ( \frac{n \pi}{2} \right )-\sin\left ( \frac{3 \pi n}{2} \right )}{2n \pi}$$

I want to show that for $$n\rightarrow \infty$$ the above equation reduces to
$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Evidently, this means the $2$ sine functions must cancel each other. But what is a good way to do this? Large $n$ results in sine toggling between $-1$ and $1$. Notice that the either sine function will have a sign opposite to the other.

Comment: How would $\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ behave for large $n$?

Comment: By Squeeze theorem, I reckon it goes to zero.

Comment: Mathematicing is right - it goes to 0.  The second and third terms in your problem tend to 0 in the same way.

Comment: Jesus, the amount of answers something like this gets in under 5 minutes is too much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two $\sin$ functions needs not cancel each other. We have
$$\sin(nx) - \sin(3nx) \in [-2,2]$$
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{n\pi-2}{2n\pi} \leq \dfrac{n\pi + \sin(nx) - \sin(3nx)}{2n\pi} \leq \dfrac{n\pi+2}{2n\pi} $$
Now take $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @ZainPatel No. For $n=1$, we have $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$ and $\sin(3\pi/2) = -1$.

Comment: My apologies, I've seen my mistake.

Comment: Squeeze theorem?  Yay!

Answer (score 6):

Divide numerator and denominator by $n$:
$$
\frac{n\pi+\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}2\right)-\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}2\right )}{2n\pi} = 
\frac{\pi+\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)}n-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}2\right )}n}{2\pi}\to\frac{\pi+0+0}{2\pi} = \frac12
$$
because $\sin$ is a bounded function.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that

$$\begin{align}
\sin(\frac{3n\pi}{2})&=\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}+n\pi) \\
&=\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})\cos(n\pi)+\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})\sin(n\pi) \\
&=\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})\cos(n\pi)+0 \\
&=(-1)^n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})
\end{align}$$

and hence

$$\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})-\sin(\frac{3n\pi}{2})=(1-(-1)^n)\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$$

The above expression is $0$ or $2$ depending on $n$ is even or odd. Now, you can find a bound easily

$$0 \le (1-(-1)^n)\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) \le 2$$

And finally

$$\frac{1}{2} \le \frac{n \pi+\sin\left ( \frac{n \pi}{2} \right )-\sin\left ( \frac{3 \pi n}{2} \right )}{2n \pi}\le \ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{ n \pi}$$

Now, you can guess what happens next! :)

Comment: Infinite is neither odd nor even, creating problems for your method.

Comment: @SimpleArt: When we talk in sequences we mean integers! :) Anyway I have another error! :)

Comment: XD.  When did we start talking about sequences.  I thought we were taking a limit to infinite and therefore must consider more than integers.  Nice try, sorry the other guy beat you to the answer.

Comment: @simpleart, you misunderstand the approach. For each member of the sequence HR demonstrated the sine terms cancel. Thus the sequence doesn't have them to begin with. It has nothing to do with the parity of infinity.

Comment: We had this conversation before in another question with other users. Let me ask you this what are the differences between $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n\pi)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x\pi)$? When we write $n$ we are in integers by convention!

Comment: This question was posed implicitly as the limit of a sequence. The use of the variable n implies this. No need to be rude @simpleart

Comment: @Joel Oh, yes, I can understand.  ok, ok, I've got it.  It bothers me a little though.

Comment: @Joel, no.  I just want to learn and understand everything.  I don't mean to be rude.  Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{n\pi+\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}{2}\right)}{2\pi n}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{2\pi n}-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}{2}\right)}{2\pi n}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{2\pi n}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}{2}\right)}{2\pi n}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{2\pi n}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}{2}\right)}{2\pi n}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{n}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}{2}\right)}{n}$$

Comment: (+1) I think this is more than a hint! :)